# Django: Boolean field not getting updated

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model which has a `latest` field to determine if a particular instance is the latest definition.

When adding a new row to the db I want to make sure to mark `latest` as false for the already existing record.

```
latest_version = Segment.objects.filter(title=title, latest=True).first()

if latest_version:
    latest_version.latest = False
    latest_version.save()
```

This seems relatively straight forward but the `latest` field will not update and stays as `True`.

Comment: Do you intend to use `last` instead of `first`?

Comment: you are updating just the first occurrence of the filter i.e `Segment.objects.filter(title=title, latest=True).first()` are you sure you are checking the same `Segment` object by which you have filtered. You should rather try the filter and match using `id` of that `Segment` document. Also maybe  `Segment.objects.filter(title=title, latest=True).first()` does not return anything, in which case there is no update. Overall the code seems perfect and should work as you intend it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking at the wrong object for the update. I think what you are looking for is:

```
Segment.objects.filter(title=title, latest=True).last()
```

Comment: I only intend for there to be a single instance which matches my filter query so it don't think it should make a difference between `first` and `last`. And regardless of which method I use the value of `instance.latest` does not change (for example `print(instance.latest)` after `instance.save()` still gives the value as true)

Comment: I just tried using `last` and it worked! So thanks although I don't understand what caused it to work? Any recommended reading would be appreciated!

Comment: Hope it helped. Only thing you were doing wrong was that, you were updating one object and looking at another. first() and last() are opposite to each other. And your situation required last(). Cheers